# Redirecting IE6 Users

Tags: internet-explorer-6, redirect

I am searching for an IE6 code which will redirect users from our brand new web page to an older version.

for example something along these lines

```
<!--[if lte IE6]>
<a href="http://etterengineering.com">
<![endif]-->
```

Thank you!

Comment: Ohh IE 6... what pain you have caused

Answer (score 8):

```
  <!--[if lte IE 6]>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/" />
  <![endif]-->
```

Put this in the head of your page and change the URl to the correct one. This will work even if the user has disabled JS.

Note that meta refresh is discouraged due to some associated drawbacks, but for your purposes should be good enough.

The alternative is to return HTTP 302 for IE6 user agent.

Comment: This works, however it is redirecting versions 7 and 8 as well. How can i fix this?

Comment: My bad, there should be a space between IE and the version - like this `IE 6`. I've fixed it in the answer as well.

Comment: Will this cause my site to be "blacklisted" in terms of SEO

Comment: I am not a SEO expert, but likely not, as any non-IE6 agent would ignore the redirect and follow the modern version of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!--[if lte IE6]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://etterengineering.com";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Will this cause my site to be "blacklisted" in terms of SEO?